# Is there any way to retrieve multiple records from a Twilio call?

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

I would like to know if there is anyway to retrieve multiple record from a twilio call. What I am trying to do is to get voice responses records from my users.Once I have those I would apply my own NLP software to do some Speech to text.For now what I got is a TWIml bin doing  then a  then in action url I would like to do something to do a new  and a new  everything in the same call.

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

Every time you use [`<Record>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/record) during a call and the recording completes, the URL of that recording is sent to the [`recordingStatusCallback` attribute](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/record#attributes-recording-status-callback) that you can set on the TwiML.

Once the call is complete, you can also use the [Twilio REST API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest) to [retrieve all the recordings for a call](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/recording#list-uri).

I'm not sure what else you were asking. I hope this helps.